# How to make custom validation for all datatype in c# using extension methods

Tags: c#, validation, extension-methods

hi i am want to make custom conman validation using c# extension method for all datatype please give me some idea about it and some examples?

Thanks

Comment: You would need to give some more details please check [ask] for how to ask a good question. Have you tried something that doesn't work? Please provide us with a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you do not know about variables in c#.

Please see more about variables in this link, because all types inherit from System.Object
[enter link description here](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/reference-types)

For example, this code maybe solve your problem, but I don't understand for what purpose...

```
public static class Test
{
    public static bool UserCheck(this object a)
    {
        return a != null;//ha-ha
    }
}

public class SomeProgramm
{
    public void main()
    {
        int a = 0;
        a.UserCheck();
        object b = new object();
        b.UserCheck();
    }
}
```